# Search function annoyance wth Nemo

Tags: files, search, nemo

Running Ubuntu 20 with Nemo Files 4.4.  When I search a folder I get around 3 or 4 characters in and another search function comes on that copies what I have typed and starts searching the whole computer in a new field at the bottom of the window. This is a real pain. I believe it is related to a new "feature" where random typing automatically activates a search engine?

Can this be turned off.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1377182/edit) to post some screenshots?

Comment: I can't because the stupid search window goes away the instant you press the printscreen key. Open Nemo 4 file explorer, start to type. A search field appears at the bottom right of the window.  It does not seem to have any functionality.  If you click on the search icon a functional search field appears  but when I type in that something blocks the text and moves the focus down to the search on the bottom right. Ubuntu is fully updated.

Comment: You can open the screenshot app and set a time delay before capturing. Right now, your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: So your install is a Ubuntu Core 20 installation with desktop packages installed?   Ubuntu has used the *year* format for a different stream of products (*snap* package only) since 2016; the 20 (*year* format) signifying it's *snap* only when compared to the far more common 20.04 (*year.month* format)  for example.  Please be precise with details; are you using Ubuntu Core 20?

Comment: what is unclear? Open Nemo files, start typing. A search box opens on the bottom right. It interferes with using the regular search function (clicking on the magnifying glass). I want to disable it if I can.